# How to validate uniqueness of a field without saving in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

Suppose you have `User has_many Books`. Each book has a name field.

The user enters their books and it is submitted to the app as an array of names. The array of names will replace any existing books.

If the update fails, then the books should not be changed.

```
class Book
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniquness_of :name, scope: [:user]
```

How to check the validity of each book without saving?

For example:

`['Rails Guide', 'Javascript for Dummies']` would be valid.

`['Javascript for Dummies', 'Javascript for Dummies']` would not be valid.

`params[:books].each{| b | Book.new(b).valid? }` will not work because the book has to be saves to get the uniqueness.

Mongoid

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Active Record Transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). Start the transaction, call `save`, and if it fails then the entire transaction will be rolled back. For example:

```
Book.transaction do
    params[:books].each{ |b| Book.new(b).save! }
end
```

The entire transaction is aborted if there is an exception. You should handle this case by catching `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`.

Comment: You also need a uniqueness constraint in the database and then you'd also need to catch `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.

Comment: This is a good way of doing it, but Mongo doesn't have transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to convert array of books attributes to array of books names. Then use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to remove duplicates from array of books names, and then check if resulting array has the same size as the original array of books attributes:

```
are_books_uniq = params[:books].map{|b| b[:name]}.uniq.size == params[:books].size
```

This way you can perform your check, without touching the database. But to be on a safe side, you should save all the books inside a transaction (see @Aaron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38470509/6231376)).

Comment: I didn't like this way of doing it because it duplicates the validation logic.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be much more complicated than I imagined.

The solution I came up with looks like:

```
  def update params
    names = params.delete( :books )

    new_books = names.map{| title | Book.new( name:name )}
    validate_books_for new_books 

    return false if errors.present?
    return false unless super( params )

    self.books = new_books

    self
  end
```

Most of the complexity comes from the coupling of the 2 models. I can see why it is not a good idea to couple models. Perhaps a better design would be to store the books as an array.